# Android how to crop image use xml like css

Tags: android, imageview, margin, crop

As the [image](http://imm.io/tHCE) you see, we can crop it by set a negative margin to the image and set `overflow:hidden` to its parent element.So how can I do with it in android?
I believe that the powerful Bitmap class can crop it and create a new image. Is there a simpler way such as do some-width margin or layout?

---

Here there is my solution:
I've found a better way just now and solve most of my problem:

`imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

optional code(set a little bit negative margin(padding in fact))

`imageview.setPadding(-5, -10, -5, -10);`

will resize the image to fit its parent's width or height and auto make it center

Answer (score 1):

You can crop an image using `com.android.camera.action.CROP` as

```
File tempFile = new File("mnt/sdcard/Images/beijingtesttemp.jpeg");//Image path which u want to crop
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tempFile), "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true"); 
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96); 
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(tempFile)); 
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "JPEG");
startActivityForResult(intent,PHOTOR);
```

and in `onActivityResult` get cropped image using `data.getExtras()`

```
 @Override 
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (resultCode == NONE)  
                return;  
            if (requestCode == PHOTOR) {  
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
                if (extras != null) {  
                     // get cropped image as bitmap here
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  

                }  
            }  
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
        }
```

Comment: oh~~thanks,i find a better way just now: imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); will resize the image to fit its parent's width or height and auto make it center

Answer (score 1):

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

is great but it doesn't really crops image. To crop it properly you should also use:

```
android:cropToPadding="true"
```